# Can I run Django application in both local server and Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've deployed my Django project with AWS EC2, which uses Ubuntu server. Also, I'm using Posgtres as the DB engine. Then I've made some small changes to the code, and wanted to check if it was properly made but in my local computer so only I can check at the moment. However when I used `python manage.py runserver` command, it gave me an error saying `"Is the server running on host "##MyDBInstanceID##.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"`.

 It's my first time deploying a project, and I have no idea what went wrong. Do I have to turn the Ubuntu server off while I try to access with my local computer? If that's the case, will I have to do it every time I make small changes and want to check on my own?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to have your local Django test server connect to your AWS EC2 database. What you could do is install and run Postgres locally and then point your local Django server to that. Here is the documentation on the `Host` option of the `Database` setting: [Django Database Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#host)

If you set the `Host` field to an empty string then your AWS EC2 Django server will use its (local) AWS EC2 Postgres server, whilst your own local computer Django server will also use your local Postgres set up.

Your current `settings.py` probably has something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '##Your database name ##',
        'USER': '## Your database user ##',
        'PASSWORD': '## Your database user password ##',
        'HOST': '##MyDBInstanceID##.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '', # Defaults to 5432
    }
}
```

If you just set:

```
'HOST': '' # Will connect to a localhost database
```

Then your Django server, running at `##MyDBInstanceID##.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com` will connect to the Postgres database running at that same location (localhost) on port 5432. Similarly, your own computer will connect to a localhost Postgres database on your own computer. You only need to set `HOST` if the database is on a different computer than the Django server. For the sort of test you are describing, a local database would be sufficient.

Alternatively, if you are using Git, you could add a `PG_HOST` field to a file named `local_settings.py` in the same folder as `settings.py`, then add the respective host in each location to `PG_HOST`, and add `local_settings.py` to your `.gitignore` file. Then just import `PG_HOST` in your `settings.py` and set the `Host` field to equal `PG_HOST`. That way you can set the database host independently on both your local and server instances. For example:

Create local_settings.py on AWS EC2 instance with contents:

```
PG_HOST = '##MyDBInstanceID##.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

Create local_settings.py on your local computer with contents:

```
PG_HOST = '' # Local host
```

settings.py:

```
from .local_settings import PG_HOST

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '##Your database name ##',
        'USER': '## Your database user ##',
        'PASSWORD': '## Your database user password ##',
        'HOST': PG_HOST,
        'PORT': '', # Defaults to 5432
    }
}
```

Just remember to `.gitignore` local_settings.py or else the location-specific settings will be overwritten.

You could use the `local_settings.py` file as a way to keep your postgres username and password out of your Git history too (again, if you are using git or some source control).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the nice answer. However I'm a little confused with the second paragraph. Could you elaborate a little more please? Thanks :)

Comment: @RyanOh I've updated the answer to give more information. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But when I ```python manage.py runserver```, I get this error saying ```No module named 'local_settings'```. I've typed exactly you've written above, in the settings.py. (The lower part, cause I'm using Git). What do you think is the problem? Thanks again. :)

Comment: I've only written ```PG_HOST = ''``` in the local_settings.py in my local computer, as you said.

Comment: @RyanOh You need to create a file named `local_settings.py` in the same folder as `settings.py`. In your project root directory, add a file named `.gitignore` with the contents as `/<your project name>/local_settings.py`. Then create that file on your AWS EC2 instance too. Also try change the import statement to from .local_settings import PG_HOST (note the '.') to show the relative import. I had omitted that earlier.

Comment: Oh I see. I've added the '.' , and now I get ```psycopg2.OperationalError```. I'm sorry for the serial errors. And thank you again, for your help. :)

Comment: @RyanOh That sounds like a different issue. Do you have Postgres running on your own computer and the psycopg2 package installed?